# Use data of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I can display a table of users from my database on my web application using  ng-repeat. I can add and delete directly from the web application but now I'm trying to update informations about those users. I would like to click on a button on the row of the user (each rows display informations for one user, 1 row = 1 user) when I clicked on this button I would like to make a form with input fields filled with actual values.
I can only get informations about my users by clicking on this button but I don't know how to "send" informations to this form.

My table of users :

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
...
</tr>
```

But something like this is not working at all :

```
<form>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="up_name" ng-model="user.name"/>
  <label>Age</label>
  <input type="text" id="up_age" ng-model="user.age"/>
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this synthax, your form have to be in your ngRepeat. It is not the best way to do it, as you will have a form for user.

I would suggest you something different. In your controller, set an `edit()` function:

```
$scope.edit = function(user) {
    $scope.editedUser = user;
}
```

When clicking a user in your table, call the edit() function:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="edit(user)">
    ...
</tr>
```

You can now edit in the form the editedUser object:

```
<form ng-if="editedUser">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="up_name" ng-model="editedUser.name"/>
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="up_age" ng-model="editedUser.age"/>
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following :

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-init="selectedUser = null">
   <td> {{ user.name }}</td>... <td ng-click="selectedUser = user"> edit </td> 
</tr>

<div ng-if="selectedUser">
   <form>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="up_name" ng-model="user.name"/>
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="up_age" ng-model="user.age"/>
    ...
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are talking about a sort of **master-detail** ui pattern.

Here it is a public [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/DBSbiV/) that will solve that kind of problem

Answer (score -1):

Insert the both input and span HTML directive in `<td>` and use `ng-switch` : `ng-switch-when` & `ng-switch-default` to display only one field.

```
<td class="sorting_1" ng-switch="mode">
    <input type="text" class="form-control small" ng-switch-when="edit" id="edit" ng-model="edit.username">
    <span ng-switch-default id="item.username">{{item.username}}</span>
</td>
```

You need to write a custom directive for it.Reason for writing custom directive is the value of `ng-switch`  will associate with individual instead of global.

In the last `<td>` tag add : which will contain edit and update buttons:

```
<td ng-switch="mode">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs edit" ng-switch-when="edit" ng-
  click="updateItem(edit, index)">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-switch-default ng-
  click="editItem(item)">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o "></i>
  </button>
</td>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.editItem = function(oldData) {
      $scope.edit = angular.copy(oldData);
      $scope.mode = "edit";
    }

    $scope.updateItem = function(data, index) {
      $scope.$emit('update', data, index);
      $scope.mode = "default";
    }
```

The value of input-box will be updated using
`$scope.edit = angular.copy(oldData);`  into `editItem()` function.

With the use of event emitters modify the main object.

```
$scope.$on('update', function(event, data, index) {
    angular.copy(data, $scope.items[index]);
  });
```

use `angular.copy` to deep clone value instead of passing value as a reference.

**Check**  **http://codepen.io/sumitridhal/pen/YVPQdW**